# Is it possible to make a keyboard shortcut for clicking a button on a particular website?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, web-crawler, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a button on a particular website that have to click frequently enough that it would save me a lot of time if there were a keyboard shortcut for it. Does anyone know if it would be possible to write a bash script or something that would allow you to press a keyboard shortcut, detect if your browser were in focus and on the given site, and then if so trigger the clicking of a button with a particular HTML id, or something like that?

Comment: Yes, it would be possible. I suggest doing some research into it.

Comment: There are Chrome extensions (I just googled this one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck?hl=en) that appear to allow you to set a keyboard shortcut for a snippet of Javascript.  Maybe try that?

Comment: You can make a Violentmonkey script

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at selenium. It is an automated testing tool for websites. There are libraries for various programming languages or even a chrome extension.

[Selenium website](https://www.selenium.dev/)

[Selenium python library](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

[Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-ide/mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd)